# web crawling Google - getting different results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

I have written the following Python script, to crawl and scrape headings of Google News search results, within a specific date range. Though the script is working, it's showing the latest search results, and not the ones mentioned in the list.

E.g. Rather than showing results from 1 Jul 2015 - 7 Jul 2015, the script is showing results from May 2016 (current month)

```
import urllib.request 
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#get and read the URL
url = ("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=banking&num=100&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=921&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F07%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A07%2F07%2F2015&tbm=nws")
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
html = opener.open(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html5lib")


#extracts all the links from the given page 
itmes  = bsObj.findAll("h3")
for item in itmes:
    itemA = item.a
    theHeading = itemA.text
    print(theHeading)
```

Can someone please guide me to the correct method of getting the desired results, sorted by dates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests and it seems the problem is coming from the User-Agent which is not detailed enough.
Try replacing this line:

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

with:

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"),
```

It worked for me.
Of course this User-Agent is just an example.

Comment: Thanks @Julien Salinas for your help. I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As [Julien Salinas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217005/15164646) wrote, it's because there's no [`user-agent` specified in your request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

For example, the default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217005/15164646) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you received a different HTML with different selectors and elements, and some sort of an error. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers` using `requests` library:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}
response = requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "best potato recipes",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "us",
    "tbm": "nws",
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.WlydOe'):
    title = result.select_one('.nDgy9d').text
    link = result['href']
    print(title, link, sep='\n')

----------
'''
Call of Duty Vanguard (PS5) Beta Impressions – A Champion Hill To Die On
https://wccftech.com/call-of-duty-vanguard-ps5-beta-impressions-a-champion-hill-to-die-on/
Warzone players call for fan-favorite MW2 map to be added to Verdansk
https://charlieintel.com/warzone-players-call-for-fan-favorite-mw2-map-to-be-added-to-verdansk/114014/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google News Results API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't figure out why certain things don't work, bypass blocks from search engines since it's already done for the end-user, and you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Call of duty 360 no scope",
  "tbm": "nws",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for news_result in results["news_results"]:
  print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")


----------
'''
Call of Duty Vanguard (PS5) Beta Impressions – A Champion Hill To Die On
https://wccftech.com/call-of-duty-vanguard-ps5-beta-impressions-a-champion-hill-to-die-on/
Warzone players call for fan-favorite MW2 map to be added to Verdansk
https://charlieintel.com/warzone-players-call-for-fan-favorite-mw2-map-to-be-added-to-verdansk/114014/
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more in-depth blog post about how to scrape [Google News Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-news-with-python-4o14).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.